# We noticed that the different durations of your auto-renewable subscriptions were still created as separate in-app purchase products

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit, swiftystorekit

i have create 3 different auto renew subscription of different duration in same subscription group.

Weekly,Monthly,Yearly within 1 subscription group.

App reject for below reason

Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions

We noticed that the different durations of your auto-renewable subscriptions were still created as separate in-app purchase products, rather than as different durations within the same subscription group.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i have Created 3 in app purchase products in 3 subscription group. So From apple store, They rejected my app with the reason "We noticed that the different durations of your auto-renewable subscriptions in saperate Group."

After that i have created 3 new In app purchase products in and used them in my app. But i haven't remove it from apple developer Console and submit my app for review.so again they reject app with the same reason "We noticed that the different durations of your auto-renewable subscriptions in saperate Group."

After that i remove old In app purchase products from apple developer console and submit old binary for review and App Approved.

so just create new in app purchase product with same subscription group rather than different group and Remove OLD in app purchase IDS from apple developer console.